# formData empty from multi image uploader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, append, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a multi-file uploader in Vue.js, and need to create a formData object to send the files uploaded.

I'm currently trying to do that with this method:

```
      // fileList is an obj returned by files property of HTML element (list of files)
      const formData = new FormData();
      // append files to FormData
      if (!fileList.length) return;
      Array
        .from(Array(fileList.length).keys())
        .map((x) => {
          formData.append(fieldName, fileList[x], fileList[x].name);
        });
      console.log(formData);
      this.save(formData);

    }
```

However, the formData I get back right before my this.save() call is empty, and I cannot figure out why these files are not getting appended to formData!!!

If anyone has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have also tried

```
for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        (formData.append(fieldName, fileList[i], fileList[i].name));
      }
      console.log(formData);
```

and still do not get anything back.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly print the values of formData. You need to use the following code to print the values.

Just try out the following code and let me know.

```
    let fd = new FormData();
    let x, fileCount = this.fileList.length;
    let self = this;
    for (x = 0; x < fileCount; x++) {
      fd.append(this.fileList[x]['name'], this.fileList[x]);
    }
    // Display the values
    for (var value of fd.values()) {
       console.log(value); 
    }
```